# Opening Binary files in C++, changing the mode of an open file

Tags: c++, io

I've got a program that deals with both Ascii and binary PGM images. I open the file open mode using:

```
ifstream istr(argv[i]);
```

After reading in the header of the PGM file, that determines if I'm dealing with binary data or ASCII. Is there a way then to change the istr to the binary mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1>** You would have first clear the stream by calling `Clear` method to reset the mode of the stream(required if your stream has hit an `end-of-file` or has encountered an `error`)

**2>** You would have to close the stream by calling `close` method

**3>** Finally you have to call the `open` method to open the new file with the desired filemode

Comment: will that read the header of the PGM file (first 3 lines of the file) as Binary? Those will always be ASCII data.

Comment: @Snow_Mac you can first open the file in binary mode,read the first 3 lines..close the file..reopen the file..seek to the line after the 3rd line to read the ascii data

Comment: @Snow_Mac you should refer to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no [member function in `std::ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/) to change the mode. So you'll have to `close()` and re-`open()` the file in binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not portably. You're going to have to open in binary mode and deal with line endings manually.